# Do any tools exist that allow cross platform error logging and tracking for multiple applications?

Tags: java, .net, error-handling, cross-platform

Our development team hosts many different applications both .Net and Java based. Currently, we handle our error logging with **Log4J** and use emails to alert the development team when problems arise. Currently, we get thousands of alerts a day and it's becoming a little tedious to maintain.

We've been discussing creating a central dashboard for all our apps. The ideal tool would track errors, warnings, info etc. over the life of an application (it doesn't necessarily need to be db driven). The idea is that the data can be viewed on a dashboard, drillable to specific errors with the capability of alerting via emal when triggers and or thresholds are met.

**[Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)** is good for .Net but we need a tool that could also work for Java EE? What is the best way to go about this? Should we:

- Just use Elmah for the .Net apps and find something similar for Java and build our own dashboard to create a united look & feel?

**OR**

- Is there a tool that already exists that we can leverage to do this cross platform?

I've tried looking in [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) but it's difficult to describe what I'm looking for.

Comment: my team is facing an identical scenario and has the same wants and needs.  What did you end up going with?  Thanks.

Comment: @emragins It kind of dropped off the radar. Logfaces was the most promising option but we never pursued it since we were trying to weigh the cost of developing it in-house instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you have a logging problem, I think that you have an integration problem, no matter if it is logging, or any other area your root issue is the same... How do I make my completely different components talk to each other?

There is a lot of approaches, but probably the easiest to implement for different technologies is Web services or REST... You will probably need to have a central logger that you need to implement independently, and then build a Web service/REST interface to which you are going to have to connect to...

Maybe a different line of investigation for you is to see if there is a logging product out in the market that takes web service calls... If that's the case, you only need to change your components to make a service call every time.

Something else that you need to consider is that your remote logging should never superseed your local logging, that's it do both, the reason is very simple, remote calls can fail, so code as if they will fail.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty good idea. I'll try to find a logging product out there that takes a Web Service call first. If not, we may have to implement this ourselves. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Through my searching I've stumbled across **Logfaces**:[http://www.moonlit-software.com/logfaces/web/index.php] which seems to do most of what I wanted. I'll bring this up to the rest of the team and see what they think.

Answer (score 1):

We have been using http://www.exceptional.io/ for error tracking for some time now: it's cheap and extremely simple.

To report errors you just post a json document to its endpoint.

Comment: This seems pretty geared towards Ruby, Rails and js. I understand that I *could* post .Net or Java errors using JSON but the fact that there's no explicit support for these platforms is probably enough for me to look elsewhere. What language are you doing your dev work in ?

Comment: Most of my development is .NET (mainly c#) on the server side and Javascript on the client side. Implementing the service is nothing more then making a POST to their endpoint in JSON (you can use the framework built-in JavascriptSerializer).

Comment: Cool +1. It seems like it could work. I'll see what the rest of the team thinks about it.